# Spring Service default scope

Tags: java, spring, scope

Which is the default scope of a **Spring 4** `@Service`?

Does it make sense designing a *Service* implementation to store info about the current logged user (according to the current **HTTP session**), through *class attributes* (also by using the `final` modifier)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Which is the default scope of a Spring 4 @Service?

The default scope is singleton

> It is reasonable to design a Service implementation in order to store some info, related to the current logged user (according to the current HTTP session)

Yes. In that case, the service will have to have the scope "session". See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other

Comment: Thus, I should annotate the service as `@Scope("session")`, right?

Comment: You should rather use `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` or `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)` depending on your preferred proxy mode, so that the session bean can be injected anywhere.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what was default scope for Spring 3 @service? I am having a problem with different user sessions showing the same values.

Comment: @EvaMariam Default scope has always been singleton.

Comment: When i use `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`, i getting the below error. 

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.reportBuilder': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: 

Can you suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: My Service layer is managed by spring using @service annotation only.

Comment: *No thread-bound request found* means that the call to your service isn't made from a thread used to serve a Spring-MVC HTTP request. You shouldn't hijack an old question to ask your own.

Comment: Can `@Scope` be inherited if extended from abstract class?